$\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_n=y,n<\tau)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_n=x,n<\tau)$
Suppose that we are given a discrete time Markov chain with reversible measure $\mu$. By definition,
$$\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_1=y)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_1=x)$$
and by induction we even get$^1$
$$\forall n:\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_n=y)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_n=x).$$
That being said, this paper claims that
$$\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_n=y,n<\tau)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_n=x,n<\tau),$$
where $\tau$ is a hitting time (see equation 4.18). Can someone elaborate please?

$^1$ Suppose that $\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_n=y)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_n=x)$, then
$$\mu(x)\mathbb P_x(X_{n+1}=y)=\mu(x)P^{n+1}(x,y)=\mu(x)\sum_z P^n(x,z)P(z,y)=\sum_z \mu(x)P^n(x,z)P(z,y)=\\
=\sum_z \mu(z)P^n(z,x)P(z,y)=\sum_z P^n(z,x)\mu(z)P(z,y)=\sum_z P^n(z,x)\mu(y)P(y,z)=\\
=\mu(y)\sum_z P(y,z)P^n(z,x)=\mu(y)P^{n+1}(y,x)=\mu(y)\mathbb P_y(X_{n+1}=x)$$

Let $P(x,y)$ denote the one-step transition probability $\Bbb P_x(X_1=y)$. Suppose $\tau$ is the hitting time of $A$ and that neither $x$ nor $y$ is a  point of $A$. Then
$$
\eqalign{\mu(x)\Bbb P_x(X_n=y, n<\tau)
&= \sum_{x_1\notin A,x_2\notin A,\ldots,x_{n-1}\notin A}\mu(x)P(x,x_1)P(x_1,x_2)P(x_2,x_3)\cdots P(x_{n-1},y)\cr
&= \sum_{x_1\notin A,x_2\notin A,\ldots,x_{n-1}\notin A}P(x_1,x)\mu(x_1)P(x_1,x_2)P(x_2,x_3)\cdots P(x_{n-1},y)\cr
&= \sum_{x_1\notin A,x_2\notin A,\ldots,x_{n-1}\notin A}P(x_1,x)P(x_2,x_1)\mu(x_2)P(x_2,x_3)\cdots P(x_{n-1},y)\cr
&\cdots\cr
&= \sum_{x_1\notin A,x_2\notin A,\ldots,x_{n-1}\notin A}P(x_1,x)P(x_2,x_1)P(x_3,x_2)\cdots P(y,x_{n-1})\mu(y)\cr
&= \sum_{x_1\notin A,x_2\notin A,\ldots,x_{n-1}\notin A}
P(y,x_{n-1})P(x_{n-1},x_{n-2})P(x_{n-1},x_{n-1})\cdots P(x_1,x)\mu(y)\cr
&=\Bbb P_y(X_n=x,<\tau)\mu(y).
}
$$
